# How to use CIFilterShape

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I've searched far and wide and can't find a single example of how to use a CIFilterShape, and what it's good for.  Most Apple docs just say it controls the dod of a filter, even the CoreImage Reference doesn't actually discuss how to use it.

A dumb simple assumption would be to use it transform the dimensions and offsets of a single rectangle and pass that shape directly to `-[CIKernel applyWithExtent]`.

Such a usage wouldn't really create a stenciling effect though, which is what I would expect from a filter shape.  Can anyone explain and perhaps provide some examples as to the actual usage of CIFilterShape?

Comment: It seems it only works with rectangles not arbitrary shapes from what I can tell, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_advanced_concepts/ci.advanced_concepts.html for brief mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: CIFilter slide]

It appears to be the corresponding type for the `kCIApplyOptionDefinition` key for the domain of definition (DoD) which I have only found referenced in WWDC10 session 426 slide 54 above. Here is a [link to the slides](https://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2010/session_426__core_image_effects_and_optimization.pdf) as well.